# 'Tutoyer' by the police as an insult

Tags: vouvoiement, tutoiement

I intellectually understand the difference in use of 'vous' and 'tu', but there are some nuances that I don't get.

I just read a couple intro sentences from [a news article](https://www.liberation.fr/debats/2018/10/22/stop-aux-controles-de-police-lors-des-sorties-scolaires_1686999) of the police arresting some school kids:

> ...trois de mes élèves se faisaient contrôler par des policiers à deux points différents de la gare du Nord, de retour d’un séjour scolaire à Bruxelles. ... Devant l’ensemble de la classe, ils durent ouvrir leurs valises, être fouillés, et **l’un d’entre eux fut tutoyé**.

That is presented as though it were a transgression, like they felt like they were horribly shamed.

Is it really a conscious thing in French culture to have representatives of the state to necessarily show a citizen respect, and in the linguistic case, vouvoyer them? The usual pattern is adult tutoyer's a child. Is there an expectation (a culture, or even an explicit law) that a police officer should vouvoyer *everyone*? (even those who, when the officer is out of a uniform, the officer would tutoyer). Or were the students or the author of the article making way too much out of this? Please enlighten me as to how to interpret this.

I have seen [this other](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11986/how-grave-of-a-mistake-is-it-to-misuse-tu-and-vous) tutoyer vs vouvoyer question but it did not address this particular nuance.

Comment: Also, I thought vouvoyer'ing was going out of fashion. I suppose I should start using it more often then if one can get reasonably upset at a police officer for such behavior.

Comment: The use of "tutoiment" can never be incriminated as much as being on the level of giving insult; at most it may confers the idea of a lack of respect, intentional or not; using "tutoiement" with the young has a strong tradition in France in various walks of life.

Comment: In the teacher movie *Entre les murs*, a high school student is expelled for various misbehaviours but the ostensible reason given is  "tutoiement d'un professeur".

Comment: What an interesting question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They were not school kids but young adults in *Terminale* class (~18/19 years old).

The vouvoiement is expected between adults who do not know each other in France<sup>1</sup>, except on forums and the web where this requirement is relaxed.

While sometimes reluctant to do it, police and *gendarmerie* officers have been asked since 2006  by their hierarchy to use the *vouvoiement* even with minors during police control and checks. See: [Les syndicats de police divisés sur la fin du tutoiement (Le Figaro)](http://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite-france/2012/06/26/01016-20120626ARTFIG00630-les-syndicats-de-police-divises-sur-la-fin-du-tutoiement.php)

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is not always the case in other francophone countries, especially in French speaking Canada and Africa.</sub>

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme Je ne dis pas que le tutoiement est systématique mais mon expérience (très limitée) est qu'il est beaucoup plus fréquent entre inconnus qu'en France. Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/692/le-tutoiement-et-le-vouvoiement-au-qu%C3%A9bec

Comment: Le tutoiement est plus commun au Québec, je crois en effet. Je ne l'attends pas toujours, mais me le fait parfois lancer à la figure dans des circonstances inattendues. Des vendeurs qui me conseillent, une note à la porte de l'épicerie qui déclare: *«Ne te cogne pas le nez dans la porte le Vendredi Saint, nous serons fermés. Prévois ton épicerie avant! ☺»*, une annonce dans les journaux qui m’accoste bien familièrement *«Tanné de tes fins de semaines plates?»*. Je n'approuve pas, je ne crois pas non plus à une épidémie, mais suis bien forcé de constater un certain état des faits.

Comment: A ma connaissance il n'y a pas de telle règle en Belgique pour les policiers. Néanmoins le vouvoiement reste considéré comme une marque de respect.

Answer (score 4):

En complément on peut comparer avec ceci :

> 5.Le policier doit se comporter de manière à préserver la confiance et la considération que requiert sa fonction.
>
> Notamment, le policier ne doit pas:
>  [...]
>  5°  manquer de
>   respect ou de politesse à l’égard d’une personne.
>
> [*Code de déontologie des policiers du Québec*](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cr/P-13.1,%20r.%201), ([P-13.1](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/P-13.1/), r. 1)

---

> Le Tribunal ajoute que, comme le Comité le mentionne, le tutoiement
>   n'est pas en soi un acte dérogatoire, bien que le vouvoiement soit
>   recommandé.
>
> Également, le fait de pointer du doigt en s'adressant à une personne
>   ou le fait de lui parler sur un ton élevé ne sont pas, pris isolément,
>   des actes dérogatoires.
>
> Par contre, si, au cours de la même intervention, la policière coupe
>   la parole à un citoyen, le tutoie, le pointe du doigt et s'adresse à
>   lui en criant plutôt qu'en parlant, tous ces gestes combinés
>   constituent un manque de politesse et de civilité flagrant.
>
> [*Bernier c. Simard*](http://t.soquij.ca/e9L6C) (2007 QCCQ 1136)

Ce genre d'analyse peut être utile à titre d'indicateur, sauf qu'à mon avis elle ne permet pas de tirer en soi une conclusion sur la place du vouvoiement ou du tutoiement dans la société en général, pas plus qu'une autre [anecdote](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/692) ne l'autoriserait. On sait que « le vouvoiement est une marque de politesse, mais aussi un indicateur de hiérarchie sociale qui permet de montrer son respect » ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5140)) et donc on peut penser que la politesse ne soit pas exclusivement réservée aux situations « très très » formelles mais que ce soit plutôt ce à quoi on s'attend généralement en société et ainsi avoir certaines attentes ou faire certains choix conséquemment, tout en sachant que « même si le premier contact est cordial, il est plus prudent d’utiliser le *vous* jusqu’au moment où la question est abordée, car le passage du *vous* au *tu* marque l’évolution d’une relation » ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5140)), et qu'il n'est pas toujours requis qu'elle évoluât, quoiqu'il faut savoir qu'« au Québec notamment, dire *tu* dès la première rencontre est beaucoup plus fréquent » qu'ailleurs ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5140)) et que « les adolescents et les jeunes adultes se tutoient spontanément » ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5140)) etc. (on lira au complet cet article à la BDL que j'ai abondamment cité).

---

Je m'attends à être vouvoyé si je suis client, acheteur, prestataire d'un service, justiciable etc. et je le suis presque toujours dans ces cas-là. L'expérience peut certainement varier et il y a bien d'autres contextes que ceux dont je parle ici, où l'on peut vouloir donner une place plus grande à la convivialité, à l'égalité etc. D'autre part j'aurais tendance à penser qu'au Québec on passe aussi plus facilement au tutoiement qu'ailleurs mais je ne pourrais l'étayer et ce n'est pas la question posée.

Answer (score 2):

"Vouvoyez", that is the practice of using the second person plural instead of the second person singular when talking to someone has become mandatory for police since January 1st, 2014. Manuel Valls (prime minister, socialist) considered it was a way to avoid both repeated controls on the same persons and the possible perception by the ‘suspect’ of lack of respect due to the familiarity associated with the second person. Indeed ‘face control´ (Arabic guys complain of being controled for no other reason than being arabs) is forbidden as it makes for bad feelings of insecurity brought about by this overbearing behaviour of the police and the feelings of supressed liberty and culpability that result. According to French customs in matters of politeness you should say 'vous' to any interlocutor you don't know closely - If you transgressed that convention, for instance with me, I could cut you short with a ‘Nous n’avons pas élevé les cochons ensemble’ and I'd be justified in doing it; (it is strictly up to me to decide whether or not you can say "tu" to me - you can not force me to accept being addressed to in the second person singular.)